# How to access the tabbar in a tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I want to call the "beginCustomizingItems" method to provide tabbaritem management for user,just as the iOS 7 Music app do.
So I read the Doc, It says:

> You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself
>   stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view
>   throws an exception. To configure the items for your tab bar
>   interface, you should instead assign one or more custom view
>   controllers to the viewControllers property. The tab bar collects the
>   needed tab bar items from the view controllers you specify.**

The tab bar view provided by this property is only for situations where you want to display an action sheet using the showFromTabBar: method of the UIActionSheet class.
Still, I tried it in my project:

```
 [self.tabBar beginCustomizingItems:self.tabBar.items];
```

It crashes. But I think there must be some way to access the tabbar in a tabbarcontroller.

[image: iOS7 Music App tabbar management]
Anyone can help me about it?

Comment: why do you need to call beginCustomizingItems:?

Answer (score 0):

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *customizableViewControllers; 
// If non-nil, then the "More" view will include an "Edit" button that displays customization UI for the specified controllers. By default, all view controllers are customizable.
```

at last  I find this help me with it.